# Applying different Visibility to each Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report showing hours and dollars that are written off.  Jobs for this report are classified as NRB (*non-billable*) and non-NRB (*billable*).  Each job type has its own Tablix in the report and I want to populate each Tablix based on a bit value - IsNRB.

All of the "0" IsNRB rows should populate the top Tablix and the "1" values should populate the bottom Tablix .  For the most part this is working.  What is happening, however, is that some Programs or Clients will have both NRB and non-NRB jobs, and it appears that as each Tablix works its way through the rows of the report dataset, it will capture and retain the first value for IsNRB and apply that to the entire report.

I have tried logic similar to the following in a number of places/ways:

```
=IIF(Fields!IsNRB.Value = False, Fields!CustProgram.Value, NOTHING)
```

The Grouping hierarchy of the report looks like this:

```
ProgramGroup
    ClientGroup
        Job/SubJobGroup
            Detail is here
```

I have tried setting evaluative expressions similar to the one above on TablixVisibility, GroupVisibility, RowVisibility, and in the field expression itself.  The behavior seems consistent in that the first row for that Program, Client, or Job sets the value of IsNRB for the entire report.

As a concrete example, the first Program, "Cascadia" has three rows where IsNRB = 1/True and two where IsNRB = 0/False, and the latter two rows of data are always misapplied because the value of 1/True is overriding the 0/False valued rows.

What is the proper approach to take that will allow the first Tablix to accept and display rows of data where IsNRB = 0 and the second Tablix to show those with a value of 1?  Do I need to abandon the IsNRB bit datatype and just have a distinct dataset for each Tablix?  That seems like a klunky way to approach the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter each table on the IsNRB field. Right click the tablix and select Tablix Properties.  Select filter, then then select the field you want to filter against (IsNRB) and the value your want it to be (1).

[image]

This will put all records with a 1 for the field in one table, and with a 0 in the other

Comment: Shazzam!!!  That worked.  So, rather than setting Visibility, the solution is to set a filter for the entire Tablix based on the bit value of IsNRB.  Beautiful solution!  Thanks Jonnus.